# Is there a way to trick TFS into thinking you have done a get?

Tags: tfs

i.e. the equivalent of a "p4 flush" or "p4 sync -k" if using perforce?

Thanks

Comment: (Removed perforce flag – there is no question about perforce here, really.)

Comment: Many of the `tf.exe` command line commands have a `/noget` option, where appropriate. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: tf get /noget? :) We are working with a fairly large (10Gb) set of data over the net so this would speed things up. See "Examples" in http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.current/manuals/cmdref/flush.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From that description of what `p4 flush` does, I think [`tf get /remap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) might be what you want. I have linked to the 2008 documentation page since it appears to me to have a better description than [the 2010 documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).